# Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 while execute `sudo apt-get update` command

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04, http-proxy, apt

I want to build a docker image on ubuntu 18.04.4 system.
At first, when i excute the command `sudo apt-get update`, it will occur an error

```
E: Release file for http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 121d 11h 7min 37s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

Then i change the wrong system time to the correct UTC time, the problem was solved.

```
ubuntu@raspi4:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

Then i begin to build my own docker file use command `docker build . -t ros-eloquent:test_06_04 -f Dockerfile`, the contents of docker file as below:

```
FROM ros:eloquent

ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://${my-proxy-ip:port}/"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "http://${my-proxy-ip:port}/"

RUN sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    vim \
    systemd \
    ethtool \
    linuxptp \
    openssh-server \
    ros-eloquent-launch* \
    ros-eloquent-rmw-opensplice-cpp \
    ros-eloquent-rmw-cyclonedds-cpp

RUN systemctl set-default multi-user.target
......
```

When the `RUN sudo apt-get update && ...` step was executed, the error info as below:

```
Step 4/10 : RUN sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y     vim     systemd     ethtool     linuxptp     openssh-server     ros-eloquent-launch*     ros-eloquent-rmw-opensplice-cpp     ros-eloquent-rmw-cyclonedds-cpp
 ---> Running in 42bc7b8f1610
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.150), connection timed out
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to packages.ros.org:80 (140.211.166.134), connection timed out Could not connect to packages.ros.org:80 (64.50.236.52), connection timed out Could not connect to packages.ros.org:80 (64.50.233.100), connection timed out
Reading package lists...
```

It was wired, cause when i execute `sudo apt-get update` solely in terminal, it works fine, but when i execute docker command `docker build . -t ros-eloquent:test_06_04 -f Dockerfile`, the connetion timed out error occur, Does anyone have any clue on this? Appreciate.

PS : also when i execute `wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports` command in terminal, it can receive response normally.

Comment: That seems like a network-level issue and not something that can be fixed in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Solved it. My docker version is 19.x.x, a better choice for setting http proxy should use file `~/.docker/config.json`, The above method also works, but need to change `ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://${my-proxy-ip:port}/"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "http://${my-proxy-ip:port}/"` to `ENV http_proxy "http://${my-proxy-ip:port}/"
ENV https_proxy "http://${my-proxy-ip:port}/"`,  official document [docker proxy](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/) does not metion this, maybe the uppercase is only fits the Docker 17.06 and lower, well, who knows.